# Autocompletion restriction in certain region of file in vim

Tags: python, autocomplete, vim

Suppose we have an xml file like this:

```
<tag1>
somthing here
</tag1>
<tag2>
somthing here
</tag2>
<region>
autocomplete here
</region>
```

Whenever the cursor in within the region tag, I want the autocompletion `c-n` and `c-x c-l` to be restricted to a some custome options, for example:

with `c-n`:

```
myword1, myword2, myword3, myword4
```

with `c-x c-l`:

```
myline1
myline2
myline3
myline4
```

Is it possible?

Solutions in python would be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a custom completion function can do that.

#### Fixed values depending on location

Vim has *dictionary completion* for a fixed set of words, cp. `:help i_CTRL-X_CTRL-K`. To configure different sets based on the location, an `:autocmd CursorMoved,CursorMovedI` could change the underlying `'dictionary'` option.

Alternatively, you can write a custom completion function, as the `CompleteMonths()` example found under `:help complete-functions`.

#### Dynamic values depending on Vim range

My [CompleteHelper plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3914) makes it very easy to write custom completions. With regular expression atoms like `\%l`, you can restrict the range where matches are found. The plugin page has links to several custom completions written with it.

#### Dynamic values depending on XML structure

To only get matches from certain XML tags, we're moving from general text editing to IDE-like features. You'd probably need an external XML parser (as parsing XML via regular expression is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)), but can then follow the recipe for custom completion functions given above.

Comment: Nice. How can I make c-x c-k respect `set infercase`?

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: ok. I am thinking to put a pair of {} within the region tag and remove it later, does it help location recognition? I still don't know how to use cursormoved for that purpose.